# Fourier transformation on a torus and the definition of fractional Laplacian

Tags: fourier-analysis, fractional-calculus

as we know, in $R^n$, for a function $f$, we can define its Fourier transform as
$$\hat f(\xi)=\int_{R^3}f(x)e^{-ix\cdot \xi}d x,$$
with this, the Laplacian of $f$ can be elegently defined by
$$\widehat{-\triangle f}(\xi)=|\xi|^2\hat f(\xi).$$
Also, the fractional Laplacian is defined by
$$\widehat{(-\triangle)^\alpha f}(\xi)=|\xi|^{2\alpha}\hat f(\xi).$$

What I want to know is the corresponding result for functions defined in a torus $T^n=R^n/Z^n$.

Would you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the 1D torus (periodic chain) the problem is solved 
in http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5904
Feel free to contact me if further questions or comments arise.
Best wishes
TM